SharePoint 2019 on-prem PDF error message
We are using SharePoint 2019 on-prem, and are having an issue with a few PDF documents that are being loaded to a document library.  When a user tries to open the PDF, they get a "Failed to load PDF" error message.  I've tried resaving the PDF, renaming the PDF, and uploading the PDF to a different library, but still get the error message.  Not all PDF documents behave that way; I uploaded one last week without any issue.  And the file size isn't an issue.  I've checked the PDF to see if there are any security issues, but the PDF doesn't show any.
Has anyone had this issue and know how to resolve it?
Thanks!

The “Failed to Load PDF Document” error message indicates that the web browser you are using, Google Chrome, is trying to open the electronic transcript within its own native PDF viewer. Because the transcript is a secured PDF, it must be opened with Adobe Acrobat Reader. Even if Adobe Acrobat Reader is already installed on your computer, if another program (like Chrome) tries to open the file you will get an error message.
To ensure that the transcript file opens, please open Adobe Acrobat Reader first, then go to file, select open, locate the transcript in your Downloads folder, and open it.
